# Unmarshal generates null field on generic with a List<T> field

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I have a Web Service created in Java (1.6), with metro (2.0), using maven, under Tomcat 6.
In all web methods the return type is a generic class:

```
public class WsResult<T> {
    protected T result;          // the actual result
    protected Code requestState; // 0K, or some error code if needed
    protected String message;    // if error, instead of result, insert a message
}
```

For example:

```
public WsResult<OtherClass> someMethod(...);
public WsResult<Foo> someMethod_2(...);
```

And in client:

```
MyServiceService service = new MyServiceService();
MyService port = service.getMyServicePort();

WsResult result = port.someMethod(...);
OtherClass oc = (OtherClass) result.getResult();

WsResult res = port.someMethod_2(...);
Foo o = (Foo) res.getResult();
```

In some web methods it is working.
But when the result is a class with have a `List<? class>` attribute, it fails to unmarshal.

This project is part of a biggest one. So for test purposes I created a new one, simpler, just the project, with the same data model, and copy one of the web methods, in this case it worked, and after unmarshal, I had a result that i could cast to the expected type.

What could be happening?

**EDIT:**

**The answer is a solution yes, but generates a getter for each type added to the field declaration.
Is there a better way?**

Comment: Can you post the relavant snippets from the test project?

Comment: Sorry for just comment now, but I'm being very busy. Edited the post, with usage example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I fully understand your problem, but to me it seems you expect a little too much from JAXB here. Your `WsResult` is generic in the unrestricted parameter `T`, which means at runtime there's nothing left but an `Object` reference for JAXB to play with.

What JAXB really needs to deal with such a situation is, loosely speaking, a hint on which class to instantiate to fill the `result` field. To fill this in you should either

- create concrete subclasses of `WsResult` (like, following your example, `class OtherClassResult extends WsResult<OtherClass>` -- when you throw the `OtherClassResult` at JAXB, it will know that `result` needs to be an instance of `OtherClass` and has a chance to act accordingly or
- annotate the `result` field with `@XmlElements`, like this:

> ```
> @XmlElements({
>     @XmlElement(name = "text", type = String.class), // add more elems here
>     @XmlElement(name = "other", type = OtherClass.class)})
> protected Object result;
> ```

Comment: In order to have it working, I'm using concrete subclasses of WsResult, but I would like to change it to a generic. I didn't understood the second option, what result field? I have no fields. The client variable or the web method body variable?

Comment: So I guess you would have to go with option 2 (or some other option I'm not aware of).

Comment: I meant the `protected T result` in `WsResult`, this should get the annotations. They are available at runtime so JAXB can figure out what to do.

Comment: Yes, you have to list any class to use it with in that annotation. The name is the name of the XML tag which should be mapped to the class given in the type parameter.

Comment: I tested it, seams to work, but now in client, for the result, I have a getter for each class element in the XmlElements, don't appear to be elegant, but at least I have the generic working. Also needed to add @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) to the class definition.